# how to set icon instead of placeholder angular 2

Tags: angular, filter, datatable, placeholder, primeng

I have implemented filter of [datatable of primeng.](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/filter) 
my code is as below:

```html
<p-column field="time" header="Time" [filter]="true" filterPlaceholder="" filterMatchMode="in">
  <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-col>
    <p-multiSelect [options]="timeOptions" styleClass="ui-column-filter" (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value,col.field,col.filterMatchMode)"></p-multiSelect>
  </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

and output is like this:

[image]

But I want search icon instead of dropdown field. Can anyone suggest any solution?

Comment: ```But I want search icon instead of dropdown field ?``` Means you need text search filter inplace of dropdown ? will you please explain a bit ?

Comment: dropdown is for search only.. I just need search **icon**, which shows dropdown list on click..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive that by simply using `[hidden]` and one more extra variable `showFilter` :

```
<p-column field="time" header="Time" [filter]="true" filterPlaceholder="" filterMatchMode="in">
  <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-col>
    <i class='fa fa-search' (click)='showFilter = !showFilter'></i>
    <p-multiSelect [hidden]="!showFilter"
                    [options]="timeOptions" 
                    styleClass="ui-column-filter" 
                    (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value,col.field,col.filterMatchMode)">
    </p-multiSelect>
  </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

Comment: @SargamSanghani, Glad to know , Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement templating.

If you need a simple solution then you can override the css class.

```
.fa-caret-down:before {
    content: "\f002";
}
```

Before adding this, add an named css class in the **multiselect** component by adding `[styleClass]` property.
This way you can avoid get affected in other **font-awesome** classes in your project.